# How to display recent posts added in custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have tried a code posted here>>[Custom Post Type: Get most recent permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/custom-post-type-get-most-recent-permalink)

But the thing is-it is showing only one post from the recent and without get_the_title,,, can anyone help me to achieve, upto 10 posts' Title and permalink of custom post type.

I am googling from about 1 hour.. Please anyone help me

Comment: Please .... show you full code here instead of linking to a tutorial. This is lazy and just adds to the number of questions that suffer from link rot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The answer is essentially in Codex!](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/)

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>'book'));
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

The only thing I did was add an argument to search for the `book` post type instead of the default `post` type.

And this is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124881/21376) anyway, but the system won't let me mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to use WP_Query, you can use following code to get recent 10 posts for any custom post type .

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your-custom-post-type',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
     );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get recent posts

```
$recent_posts = get_posts(  array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby'  => 'post_date', 'order'=> 'DESC', 'post_type' =>  array('camp','cruise','competition','combine')));
```